# RAILS: assigning an input field with information selected from a dropdown selector

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am a bit confused on the below, if one could advise me, i would be grateful

i have the below tables in my schema

**schools**

```
t.string "name"
t.string "address"
t.string “town”
t.integer "category_town_id"
```

**category_towns**

```
t.string "name"
```

**models**

```
school belongs_to :category_town
category_town has_many :schools
```

**schools controller**

```
def create
    @user = current_user
    @school = @user.schools.create(school_params)
    @school.town = @school.category_town.name

    respond_to do |format|
      if @school.save
    redirect_to @school
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @school.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

**what i would like to do is:**

- when a school is created and `category_town_id = 2` is selected assign `town` to the same information as `category_town_id = 2`
- so for example if `@school.category_town.name` is `London` ensure that `@school.town` is also `London`
- i tried doing this in the create action of the controller `@school.town = @school.category_town.name` but this does not seem to work

your advise would be much appreciated

Comment: One obvious bug in this is `@user.schools.create(school_params)`. This should be `.new` not create. Otherwise you will create two queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@school = @user.schools.create(school_params)
@school.update_attributes(town: @school.category_town.name)
```

OR

```
@school = @user.schools.new(school_params)
@school.town = @school.category_town.name
@school.save
```

The first will create the record and then update the attribute on the school object. The second will initialize a new instance of the school, adjust the town attribute. But then you need to call save on the object to persist the changes